# Packaged Obfuscated javascript Android app doesn't work when distributed and installed

Tags: javascript, android, package, obfuscation, titanium

I created a working debug version of an Android app, installed it on my phone and works perfectly. I should also mention the javascript aspect of my app has been Obfuscated. I use Titanium developer to create my application.
Now the time came to sign, zipline, package and distribute my Android app. I then installed my distributed Obfuscated app into my phone from the market. To my horror, it does not work! Whats happening here? I don't get it. It worked just fine before it was packaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If javascript calls your app methods, they shall not be obfuscated, keep them in proguard.cfg.

Stéphane

Comment: Thanks for answering in a timely fashion Stephane. But the thing is that I didn't develop my app using Eclipse. Only with Titanium developer. So no Java involved. My app is entirely built using javascript.

Comment: Does Titanium have a guide to obfuscation? If not I wouldn't recommend doing it. Also you should have tested it again after obfuscation and before publishing it to the Market.

Comment: I actually did test it even after obfuscating the app. Thats the thing which baffles me. It should be working.

Comment: There is no difference between an exported app and a published app. Uninstall your app and try again to run the exported app, as if you would publish it, it should reproduce the problem you get with the published version.

Comment: Snicolas, when you say exported app, do you mean an app that has been signed and ready for the market? If so, what methods could I use to install the exported app? I've tried moving the signed apk into the usb storage space on my Nexus S. But wouldn't know how to go about installing it.

Comment: Personally, I like to use dropbox to deploy my apps on my android device. It's quite convenient and as my usb is not correctly detected by my linux distro it is a good workaround to put files on my device.

Comment: (so you didn't test before publishing !! oh that's so bad a practice !)

Comment: lol...to be honest, due to my slight compulsive behaviour, I tested it multiple times before signing and after signing the app. This problem is a heart stopper. ;S

Comment: aaahh...I figured out how to fix this. Thank you to those who wrote in!

Comment: I just had to place the js code within the html and not just a link. Apparently a packaged app won't be able to recognize the external js files.